# AppleScript to create VirtualHost

Tags: apache, apache2, applescript, privileges, virtualhost

I'm trying to write an AppleScript which will add new virtualhost by name and absolute path.

It works when I try on test files (txt files on desktop) but when I try real files (/private/etc/hosts and /private/etc/apache2/extras/httpd-vhosts.conf) it just does not work.

The problem seems to be somewhere around user permissions, but I have no idea how to open file for writing as administrator. I tried just the way I'm doing 'do shell script' but it does not work (ar probably I'm using incorrect syntax)

My code:

```
on run (input)
display dialog "New VirtualHost name" default answer ""
set VirtualHostName to text returned of result

display dialog "Absolute path to VirtualHost's root" default answer "/Library/Webserver/Documents"
set VirtualHostRoot to text returned of result

try
    set hostsNL to "\n127.0.0.1 " & VirtualHostName

    set httpdVhostNL to "\n<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
ServerAdmin foo@example.com
ServerName " & VirtualHostName & ".local
DocumentRoot '" & VirtualHostRoot & "'
ErrorLog '/private/var/log/apache2/" & VirtualHostName & "-error_log'
CustomLog '/private/var/log/apache2/" & VirtualHostName & "-access_log' common </VirtualHost>"

    set hosts to open for access (POSIX file "/private/etc/hosts") with write permission
    write hostsNL to hosts starting at eof
    close access hosts

    set httpdVhosts to open for access (POSIX file "/private/etc/apache2/extras/httpd-vhosts.conf") with write permission
    write httpdVhostNL to httpdVhosts starting at eof
    close access httpdVhosts


    do shell script "apachectl graceful" with administrator privileges


    return true
on error
    try
        close access hosts
        close access httpdVhosts
    end try
    return false
end try end run
```

Or: is there other simlpe way to create virtual hosts?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than performing the bulk of the work in the AppleScript, do it in a shell script. Pass the virtual host name & document root as command line arguments to the shell script, which you execute with admin privileges.